# Probability of scoring positive in a certain test .

Tags: probability, contest-math, puzzle

In a math contest problem appeared which I have trouble solving . It goes as under - Consider an examination of $N$ questions - fully multiple choice questions . There are $c$ choices for each question. And marking **for each question** scheme as follows -

If the candidate chose the answer correctly then he get $+M$ and for every false answer he gives he receives $-m$. (Where $M>m)$.
Given that he guesses all the questions , calculate the probability of him scoring a positive total  .

Comment: Does he attempt all the questions or it is arbitrary?

Comment: He attempts all qquestions .

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ denote the positive number of guesses.

For positive score:
$Mx-m(N-x) >0 \implies x>\frac{mN}{M+m}$

Probability that his guess is correct is $\frac{1}{c}$

Then, the required probability for scoring positive marks is $(\frac{1}{c})^{\lfloor\frac{mN}{M+m}\rfloor}$